Querying count of specific events in splunk
My application's log is accessible through Splunk and some code in my application responds to specific webhook events from Kubernetes for example validate and mutate.
I want to know the occurrence of validate and mutate requests being executed in a specific time frame. For example , in last 1 hour, total count of mutate is 100 and validate is 110.
How do I get this from splunk log (which has its own web interface). I am totally new to Splunk and only can perform some pattern search etc.

You can have something like stats count(eval(action="mutate)) as mutate
